# nm-connection-editor not showing the full list of networks

Tags: wireless, network-manager

I'm running ubuntu 18.04 with a custom i3 desktop that launches nm-connection-editor when an icon on my bar is clicked. What's annoying me is that nm-connection-editor doesn't appear to be showing me the full list of wireless connections available, only the ones that I've already connected to in the past. Is there a way to get this thing to display the full list of networks, and if not, is there a GUI program that can be launched from the command line that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to `man nm-connection-editor`

```
DESCRIPTION
       nm-connection-editor  is  a GTK‐based application to add, remove, and modify network connections stored
       by NetworkManager.  NetworkManager must be running for any network connections to be added, removed, or
       modified
```

this means you need to click this network at-least once in order to show this when you open `nm-connection-editor`

the GUI way to launch from command line is

`gnome-control-center wifi`

[image]

Observe in below Image, there is no gear icon for the Network `iBall-Baton` this means I haven ever even tried to connect to this network..

[image]

Even I dont know the password if I just click it and then open `nm-connection-editor`, this network will be shown.

[image]

Comment: I super appreciate this comment. As it has been very helpful, however, when I 'gnome-control-center wifi' I get a blank menu that says 'devices' see the following screenshot https://imgur.com/GwJOLiy  if I hit the back arrow it tries to go back, but forces me back to the blank screen. Any idea what this means and how I can get it to show the full list of networks? Note, my wireless card seems to be working, as im connected with it right now, and have used command line tools to display a list of networks before

Comment: fixed it, the following command let it open with connections. Since I am using i3 as my desktop, it needed a little more: 'env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME gnome-control-center wifi'